# How to register child component inside parent component angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2. I am facing issue in registering child component in parent component.

AppComponent -- parent component

HeaderComponent --child component

Angular docs says that that we need to use directive:[HeaderComponent] in parent but it gives Error 
**EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on HeaderComponent**

ParentComponent:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header';
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template:"<my-header></my-header>",
   directives: [HeaderComponent] 
})
export class AppComponent {
   name="Angular 2";
   constructor(){

   }
}
```

Child Component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector:"my-header",
  templateUrl:"app/header/header.html"
});

export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor() {
    // code...
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` in `@Component` of `HeaderComponent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators should be placed directly above the class declaration, so you are not allowed to add ';' after its declaration.

Your error is because Angular does not recognize HeaderComponent as an Angular 2 component.

So, just get rid of the ';' sign inside HeaderComponent's declaration.